# Want to focus element with cssSelector. How can i do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium

Here is my css Selector codes

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='btn-link'][data-sugg-technik='append_numbers']")).click(); 

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='btn-link'][data-sugg-technik='make_pairs']")).click();
```

They are working, and I want to focus these elements with Selenium. How can I do this?

Edit:

```
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('button,btn-link,make_pairs).focus();");
```

And also this code is working, but always focuses the first item, which is not what I want.

```
<li>
  <button class="btn-link" data-sugg-sources="email,full_name" data-sugg-technik="make_pairs">AlZehraala16</button>
</li>
```

I want to focus just this button.

Comment: Have you tried `.focus()`?

Answer (score 0):

there are two say you can do it. You can do it using webdriver code or javascript. I guess using webdriver is much better as it uses native events. Following code shows how to do using webdriver.

```
@Test
public void focusElement(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1000,300));
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(searchBox).build().perform();
}
```

if you want to do that using **JavaScript**. This is how you need to modify your code.

```
public void focusElement(WebElement element){
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].focus();", element);
    }

}
```